# Python functions with underscore

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there some difference between functions defined in python as
`__func__()` and `func()`.
What is the use of adding underscores in front and back ?

Comment: double underscore on both front and back is mainly used to indicate [magic methods](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html) , I would suggest not to use them for user defined functions/methods (to avoid confusion) .

Comment: They aren't magic functions but are used in classes so as to provide better help like __init__  function initializes a.class, __str__ is for string representation, __cmp__ to compare, etc.